# Close dialog box from within AJAX loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a jquery ui dialog that loads its content via ajax:

```
$('#register').click(function(e) {
    var tag = $('<div></div>');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'signup.html',
        success: function(data) {
            tag.html(data).dialog({modal: true}).dialog('open');
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

I have a second script within the content that is supposed to close the dialog when the submit button is pressed

```
$(function() {
    $('form #submit').click(function(e) {
        $(this).parents('.ui-dialog').dialog('close');
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```

When i click the submit button, i get the error:

> Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization;  attempted to call method 'close'

What is it that i am missing to allow me to close the dialog from the content that has been loaded via ajax?

Comment: Where is the `tag` appended to the DOM?

Comment: i dont append it manually, jquery appends it to `body` automatically.

Comment: Yes, of course. You have to call dialog('close') on the `tag` element not on the `$('.ui-dialog')`. You can find it inside the `$('.ui-dialog')` elemnt like `$('.ui-dialog #signup-id')` but you have to change `tag` variable to `tag = $('<div id="signup-id"></div>');`

Comment: I tested it on this [example](http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/dialog/modal-message.html)

Comment: worked perfectly, submit as an answer and ill accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `dialog('close')` on the element where `dialog('open') was called before. You're calling the function on`$('.ui-dialog')`instead of`$('.ui-dialog ...')`.

You should define id or class for the tag element in your code:

```
var tag = $('<div id="signup-id"></div>');
```

Then find the correct element in click handler like this:

```
$(this).parents('.ui-dialog').children('#signup-id').dialog('close');
```

**Note**: You can find `#signup-id` in click handler directly like `$(this).children('#signup-id')` if you're sure that `signup.html` never contains element with `signup-id` id.

Answer (score 0):

Define you tag dialog in html

```
<div id="tag_dialog" style="display:none">
</div>
```

then on document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tag_dialog').dialog({
        modal:true,
        autoOpen:false,
        //you could give some other options such as width, height .....
    });
    $('#register').click(function(e) {
       $.ajax({
           url: 'signup.html',
           success: function(data) {
               $('#tag_dialog').html(data).dialog('open');
           }
       });
       e.preventDefault();
       return false;
   });
    $('form #submit').click(function(e) {
        $('#tag_dialog').dialog('close');
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```